# Laravel get unique rows from eagerloading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got a `collection` that `belongsToMany` products. The pivot table looks like this:

```
id
collection_id
product_id
size
```

I want to get all collections with their unique products (no duplicates!).

My query looks like this:

```
$collections = Collection::with(['products' => function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('size', $sizes);
        }])->whereHas('products', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('size', $sizes);
        })->active()->get();
```

Right now I obviously get duplicates, how can I fix this. I already tried `->unique('products.id');` but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause)

The distinct method allows you to force the query to return distinct results

```
 $collections = Collection::with(['products' => function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('size', $sizes)->select('products.id')->distinct();
        }])->whereHas('products', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('size', $sizes);
        })->active()->get();
```

Comment: thankyou! The problem with distinct is that I need all columns. Right now I only get `products.id`.